# Is there a name for this particular kind of tree graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

I've recently encountered a problem which heavily involves analysis of structures analogous to weighted trees with no nodes of degree two (such a node along with its adjacent edges would be indistinguishable from a single edge with weight equal to that of said two edges combined). In doing research on the problem, I am hampered by not knowing the structure's proper name. Does such a name exist?

Comment: The keyterm [graph homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)) may be of interest, but I've never seen it used to describe weighted graphs. This might be a good question to ask on [ComputerScience.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the term, it does seem like it might be useful. The weighting of the graph is incidental to the analysis I need to do. I was hoping that there would be some term like 'smooth', based on the page you linked, to describe such a graph.

Comment: You could describe your smooth graph to be the "*homeomorphic graph of minimum order*" (because the smooth graph with no degree-2 vertices would have to have the lowest order of all graphs equivalent under homeomorphism). I don't know if there is already some name for this in the literature, though.

Comment: I recommend asking the question on mathoverflow.com: they often are more familiar with more advanced topics.  Though try not to ask too often over there...